# Swing getLocationOnScreen method on component inside a layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

Help needed on this:

I tried to call getLocationOnScreen() on each component I placed inside a FlowLayout and getting the same position in the end.

Is this by design or did I do something wrong? How should I get each components exact location then?

There's the example I just created

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label " + i);
    panel.add(label);
    System.out.println("getLocationOnScreen-" + i
        + " x:" + label.getLocationOnScreen().x
        + " y:" + label.getLocationOnScreen().y);           
}
```

It prints in the console as:

```
getLocationOnScreen-0 x:0 y:44
getLocationOnScreen-1 x:0 y:44
getLocationOnScreen-2 x:0 y:44
getLocationOnScreen-3 x:0 y:44
```

Great appreciation if you can help on this!
Thanks!

Comment: If this is done before the frame is shown, you will get an exception. If it's done after, the frame needs to be revalidated with every new add, in order to get the location at that specific instance in time of add. Note in the latter case, the location will not be the correct locations after the loop is finished, as the labels will shift with every add

Comment: Maybe explain what you're trying to achieve will help in solving any "real" problem. I highly doubt the use case is printing the location

Comment: Add `panel.validate()` to your loop to see what happens.

Comment: @peeskillet Hi, thanks for comments, the actual use case would be showing a ballon popup related to the label in the layout.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland Thanks , it seems validate helps on this

Comment: *[...]the actual use case would be showing a ballon popup related to the label in the layout.* Are you looking for [tool tip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html)? @JunjieChen

Comment: @dic19 or [baloon tip](https://balloontip.java.net/) :-D

Comment: @peeskillet: Awesome! I didn't know about balloon tip :) Could you make an answer with an example? I'll upvote that for sure.

Comment: @dic19 Someone posted a question about it a while back and I saved the link as a favorite. Never got around to playing with it. As for an answer, I think a ToolTip answer would suffice ;-)

Comment: I have used baloontip, its really nifty to display validation messages, warnings and stuff. The only complaint I ever had with it is that baloon tips can't go outside the host window, which could be a problem when your windows is pretty small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488897/swing-getlocationonscreen-method-on-component-inside-a-layout#comment41612446_26488897):

> *... the actual use case would be showing a ballon popup related to the label in the layout.*

It seems like you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you are asking about components location on screen but what you really want to do is to display a popup balloon for each label.

Swing has such feature in-built and its called tool tip. Take a look to [How to Use Tool Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) lesson to learn how to use them.

Additionaly as @peeskillet suggested there is a third-party library available called [Balloon tip](https://balloontip.java.net/) which is worth to take a look at.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful and genius comments, I checked Ballon tip and it looks to fit so well!